# How do I fix PHP Notice - Undefined index: releaseDate?

Tags: php, admin, updating

I'm getting this error:

```
Undefined index: releaseDate in craft/app/etc/behaviors/AppBehavior.php(500)

Line 500: $row['releaseDate'] = DateTime::createFromString($row['releaseDate'], null, false);
```

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

I've run into this issue myself with Craft version: 2.6.2962.

The line in question is expecting a column from the database called "releaseDate".
In my case, that column no longer exists. It might have gotten dropped or lost with one of the updates, I am not sure.

A short-term solution would be to edit that line of code and pass in some different value.

In my case, I changed the line to:

```
$row['releaseDate'] = DateTime::createFromString($row['dateUpdated'], null, false);
```

And to clarify, looking at the changelog, it seems they are in the process of tweaking the craft()->releaseDate() function call.

Update 03/06/2017:
It appears that my code-base was outdated with the version in my database. I updated to the latest version of craft and that line that I edited above is now gone.

My question to you: Is your craft version up to date?

Comment: Thanks for the help sturakov. I updated to the latest 2.6.2966 and this began happening, although my live site works perfectly and doesn't show this error. This only seems to happen on my local .dev version.

I also can't find the:

`$row['releaseDate'] = DateTime::createFromString($row['releaseDate'], null, false);` 

from line 500.

Comment: Just to verify, you're saying you updated to the latest version and the error is still happening? And no problem, happy to help.

Comment: Yep, I've updated, but my local version is getting this error. The live site is working fine. Quite strange, not sure what to do?

Comment: Yeah, definitely strange. Are you getting the same error message even though the line is missing from that file? If so, that makes me think there's some sort of caching going on. I'm not sure what you're development environment is like, but if you give me some details, we might be able to narrow it down.

Comment: Yep, I'm getting to the same error message. I've tried to find that line in Sublime, but doesn't seem to exist. I'm running Mamp Pro 3.5.2, PHP 7.0.8 and Craft 2.6.2966 according to `info.php` in the `app` folder.

Comment: That is really, really strange. I wonder if it's being cached somehow? Have you tried restarting the system / web-server?

Comment: I have, but it doesn't seem to work. I'm committing to GitHub and the local dev version is working on other computers. I've tried deleting my files and re-cloning my repository again, but it seems to be stuck with this issue. When I initially installed the `2.6.2966` update it didn't recognize the changes on the local version, but when I pushed the changes the live version updated. My local one seems to be stuck and I can't work on the site.

Comment: Well that really sucks.
Does your local MAMP install rely on having your files in the web-server path?
For example, if you develop say locally, on your main machine (assuming OS X), do you then have to upload them to the web-server directory?

Comment: Not sure I quite understand, how do you mean sorry? My local site gets pushed to GitHub and then deployed to the live environment via DeployBot. Not sure that helps? Thanks again for helping out.

Comment: All good. Maybe we'll figure it out some day haha :).

Your deployment makes sense...
How do you use MAMP?
Like, do you edit your files, hit save, and then the changes show up when visiting a URL from your browser?
Or do you have to upload your changed file to a local web-server directory?

Comment: That's how I do it, yes. I've updated my .dev with the production database file as well.

Comment: I'm not sure what could be the problem at this point. If you want, I could attempt to help you through like a GoTo meeting or something, so I can see what you're seeing. Might be able to debug and figure out the problem that way.

Comment: Hello sturakov, thanks again for all the help. Turns out I'd pointed my .dev in Mamp to an older version of the files. Really sorry to have wasted your time, thanks for your patience. All working now, very embarrassing!

Comment: Hahaha, that's awesome! Glad you figured out what the issue was! And no worries, glad we finally got some closure. Wish you well in the future!

Answer (score 1):

1. Backup your DB.
2. I updated the CMS on my live site to the newest version.
3. download the newest version of Craft and replace `craft/app` with the new `craft/app`